# Put chart.js chart inside JQuery tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I would like to display chart.js's bar chart inside a tooltip.
Is this possible?

```
$(function() {
   $( document ).tooltip({
     track: true,
     content:function () {var temp = $(this).prop('title');
            temp = theBigArray[temp] //THIS IS THE JSON DATA CONTAINER FOR EACH SENTENCE

            var barChartData = {
                labels : ["Future","Present","Past"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                        highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data : [temp[2], temp[3], temp[4]]
                    }
                ]

            }
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            var myTable = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
                responsive : false
            });
            return  '<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>';
    }
  });
```

When "canvas" is under , and displayed on html, it works fine. But, it fails to show inside the tooltip javascript when I return the content of the tooltip with div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the canvas element before you call getElementById on it. Also, the canvas element needs to be sized for Chart.js to work properly.

Use this

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
        track: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-tooltip-content > div').append($("#canvas"))
        },
        content: function () {
            var temp = $(this).prop('title');
            var temp = theBigArray[temp] //THIS IS THE JSON DATA CONTAINER FOR EACH SENTENCE

            var barChartData = {
                labels: ["Future", "Present", "Past"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data: [temp[2], temp[3], temp[4]]
                    }
                ]
            }

            $('body').append($("<canvas id='canvas' width='200' height='100'></canvas>"))
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            var myTable = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
                responsive: false,
                animation: false
            });

            return '<div></div>';
        }
    })
});
```

with CSS

```
<style>
    body > #canvas {
        position: fixed;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

---

[image]